# Nativescript - where is the production provision files coming from (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

I'm publishing for iOS and confused as to where the provision files coming from.

I deleted all the files from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

I do a build with:

`tns publish ios my-apple-id-email my-password --team-id XXXXX`

and it seems to work.

Where is it getting the provisioning files from?

Is NS downloading it automatically.

How does it know when one to use.

Production I guess because I'm using a "publish" command.

What if I have multiple prov. profiles on developer.apple.com

Little bit confused...want to make sure I understand how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dashman with help of this "tns prepare ios --provision" command you will get provision profile detail of that project.

Detail regarding provisional profile is added in "build.xcconfig" file.

Comment: In addition, after executing `tns run ios --provision` to list the eligible provision profiles, we can build the app with a specific provision profile with `tns run ios --provision <provision-uuid>`

Comment: Thanks - I found that info and got it to work manually. Specifying team-id seems to work also with no provisions stored locally. tns/xcode seems to do it automatically - but I wasn't sure which provision was being used. Don't like it when I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I'm doing a `tns prepare ios` and then a `tns publish ios` specifying the provision id in both commands.